# How to get Grails's datasource connection for jasper reports?

Tags: grails, jasper-reports

Currently I'm adding and developing PDF export with jasper on existing JSF-based app using JasperReports JSF plugin.

Here's the thing, this app's endpoint is connected to Grails. So instead my JSF app is connected directly to the set Oracle database, my JSF app must make a request to Grails app everytime it needs data from database to return it as JSON.

In the jasper template I designed, there's a query which needs JDBC connection to my own database. In this case, I have to provide a connection object to the `fillreport` method of jasperreports plugin.

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(urlJasper, parameters, connection);
```

And this is the `fillreport` method in `JasperFillManager` object :

```
public static JasperPrint fillReport(String sourceFileName, Map<String, Object> params, Connection connection) throws JRException {
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Compiled Code">
    /* 0: invokestatic  net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.getDefaultInstance:()Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager;
     * 3: aload_0
     * 4: aload_1
     * 5: aload_2
     * 6: invokevirtual net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.fill:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/sql/Connection;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperPrint;
     * 9: areturn
     *  */
    // </editor-fold>
}
```

The main question is, can I get a connection object from Grails' Datasource? Because as far I can think, the output from Grails to JSF  are always in JSON format. Many thanks. Sorry for the bad explanations.

Comment: Nor jsf not java-se makes connections to a datasource. So I hope some grails expert can help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Inject the dataSource

`Datasource dataSource`

then call

`dataSource.getConnection()`

Comment: I'm sorry, the connection is required in JSF-app, not the Grails app.

Comment: So then what does this have to do with Grails at all?